# Can anybody identify the cap-badge and/or uniform in this image?

Tags: military, identification

Can anybody identify the cap-badge and/or uniform in this image?

I'm hoping the period is c. 1899/1900 and should be UK based???

My searches to date have turned up a blank; but then I have no military background.

[image: Robert Whinham CLARK]

Comment: Do you have a photo showing the rest of the uniform? As this could allow somebody to identify service branch, company or department and then identify the badge more easily.

Comment: [Link](http://www.uniformology.com/FORAGE-CAPS-01.html).

Comment: @Lucian Good find, but no cap badge seems to correspond. The forage cap seems to denote a either: Indian Army Staff Corps, the Commissariat & Transport Corps, the Army Service Corps, the Ordnance Store Corps Army Ordnance Department, the Army Pay Department, the Army Veterinary Department or the Inspector of Army Schools. Hard to tell without the department colours in between the two bands.

Comment: @Lucian many thanks for the link. I don’t see anything which resembles the badge on the Forage Caps pages, but the site does have a submission service which I’ll try. Cheers.

Comment: @BOB thank you immensely for the suggestions. I think we can probably rule out anything overseas. I’ll try & wade through your various hints to see if there’s a match. Sadly this is the only image I’ve found. There’s no way of discerning any colour from it, so the cap-badge is the key methinks. I’m hoping that it will have something to do with Northumberland and specifically the Hussars, but so far I can’t make the link... Anyhow, thanks again for your input. Cheers.

Comment: @LKB welcome to the site!  Comments are ephemeral, please edit your clarifications into your original question.

Comment: @LKB I think that the cap badge has a bent arm holding what looks like a tomahawk or axe, and surrounded by a laurel(?) branch.  I suggest that it is connected with a unit of "pioneers" whose symbol was an axe to cut brush and trees and clear a bath for the army, or maybe an engineer's unit.

Comment: @MAGolding Many thanks; an excellent lead I think.

Comment: The arm with hammer motif appears on the crest of the coat of arms of the city of Birmingham, and on the badge of the ship HMS Birmingham.  Perhaps the cap badge is for some Birmingham-related organization, such as (wild conjecture) the Birmingham Rifle Volunteer Corps.

Comment: @kimchilover I doubt it is the same as the crest of the Birmingham coat of arms, the one in the picture appears to be an axe or pole axe, not a hammer as the Birmingham crest is. Furthermore, the image shows a laurel or other foliage which does not appear on the Birmingham crest of the coat of arms. The Birmingham crest on the coat of arms also features a mural crown, which is absent in the image above. Lastly, the arm itself is in a different orientation and is neither vambraced or gauntleted.

Comment: @BOB Maybe.  Perhaps  it's not a military uniform at all, but the dress for a hotel employee (Maître d'hôtel, say) 
 at a fancy hotel in Birmingham.  This would account for the lack of crowns, battlements, etc, one would expect in a military badge but still account for a form of the arm and hammer.

Comment: @kimchilover Many thanks for your input. I can see the similarity, but it's highly unlikely that this man had any association with Birmingham.

Answer (score -2):

He is a senior police officer of Birmingham City Constabulary in the pre-WW1 era.

Comment: Could you also show a similar Birmingham City Constabulary officer cap-badge on another image in your reply?